# WebView android does not allow full screen

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an android application which is a webview of my site, everything was catching normally, however after updating the chrome services the application does not show more videos in full screen, in logcat it displays the following message: "**I / chromium: [INFO: CONSOLE (0)] "Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.**"

Comment: I have exactly the same problem...

Comment: Try setting        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a chrome issue.
[Issue 945287](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945287)

Comment: have other solution?

Comment: I think it's fixed, you can see in link above, "UAv2 has been enabled for WebView 74 Stable"

Comment: Read thru the whole issue #945287.  It seems the problem is fixed in M74 but as of now, Chrome update for Android is not yet released.  As of today, the Chrome for Android from Play Store is still 73.0.3683.90.  Hopefully the update will be released soon and the problem will disappear automatically.